# Groovy Script throwing FileNotFoundException using org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer on server in JMeter distributed setup

Tags: docker, groovy, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Raised a related bug after further investigation - https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65417

We're running JMeter distributed setup. There's a groovy script in our JMeter test plan which is accessing a json file and works fine on local testing (on Windows PC or alpine-based JRE-headless docker image with JMeter client and server running in same container):

```
${__groovy(new File(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + System.getProperty('file.separator') + 'message.json').text)}
```

But running the same test plan using same docker image running JMeter client and server on separate docker containers, it throws the following exception (taken from worker/JMeter server logs):

```
    2021-06-30 09:54:44,258 WARN o.a.j.f.Groovy: Error running groovy script
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/artifacts/root/artifacts/message.json (No such file or directory)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
        at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) ~[java.scripting:?]
        at org.apache.jmeter.functions.Groovy.execute(Groovy.java:120) [ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:138) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:113) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty.getStringValue(FunctionProperty.java:100) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.getPropertyAsString(AbstractTestElement.java:280) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.config.Argument.getValue(Argument.java:145) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument.getEncodedValue(HTTPArgument.java:249) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument.getEncodedValue(HTTPArgument.java:230) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.setupHttpEntityEnclosingRequestData(HTTPHC4Impl.java:1643) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.handleMethod(HTTPHC4Impl.java:886) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:641) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1296) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1285) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/artifacts/root/artifacts/message.json (No such file or directory)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:155) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/artifacts/root/artifacts/message.json (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at groovy.util.CharsetToolkit.<init>(CharsetToolkit.java:78) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.newReader(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:1780) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.getText(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:591) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$1040.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GeneratedMetaMethod$Proxy.doMethodInvoke(GeneratedMetaMethod.java:83) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:76) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:63) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:329) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
        at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1) ~[?:?]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:155) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
        ... 20 more
```

The path is incorrect (repeated root/artifacts). Is this platform issue or something we're missing in config or script?

Comment: Where you are setting `/root/artifacts` ?

Answer (score 0):

1. It doesn't look like a JMeter issue to me
2. According to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page you're supposed to "Help others reproduce the problem" and without

   - seeing your [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) and knowing the way
   - seeing where and how do you call this __groovy() function in your Test Plan
   - knowing the way you're launching your tests
   - seeing [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) files from master and slave preferably with [debug logging enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)

   I'm afraid no one will be able to help you with your problem, at least I cannot reproduce it on Linux, the base dir returned is basically the directory where I launch JMeter from without any duplication of any path fragments

[image]